# Redirect example.com/uplaod/*/*/*.zip to example.com/down.php?file=*.zip

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect by .htaccess example.com/uplaod/2009/10/test.zip  to example.com/test.php?file=test.zip

This is work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uplaod/(.*)$ http://example.com/test.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, I need only redirect special file extension (zip,7z & rar), and other files will not redirect.

Also I need to remove other folder name after upload (year & month), and only file name on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uplaod/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.+?\.(?:zip|7z|rar))$ /test.php?file=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```